# why the overwrite doesn't have the output?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

```
function rate_preprocess_rate_template_emotion(&$variables) {
  extract($variables);
  $buttons = array();
  foreach ($links as $link) {
    $button = theme('rate_button', $link['text'], $link['href'], 'rate-emotion-btn');
    $button .= $link['votes'];
    $buttons[] = $button;
  }
  $variables['buttons'] = $buttons;

  $info = array();
........
```

now i want to add `<br/><span class="pollunm">`around the `</span>`. i put this code in my theme `template.php`.but it doesn't output the span tags.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_rate_template_emotion(&$variables) {
$link['votes']='<br/><span class="pollunm">'.$link['votes'].' </span>';
}
```

Comment: Is your theme called 'mytheme'? If not change 'mytheme' to whatever your theme's called (.info file in theme folder). Have you cleared your cached data in 'Performance' section of admin?

Comment: yeap, the theme file is called mytheme,i have cleared the cache.

Comment: is mytheme_preprocess_rate_template_emotion() really called _before_ rate_preprocess_rate_template_emotion() ?

Comment: i don't know, if it doesn't call before the rate_preprocess_rate_template_emotion() how to named it in mytheme?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution. Just the step for you to debug.

1. First make sure that `function mytheme_preprocess_rate_template_emotion(&$variables)` is getting called by putting a dpm(install devel module) in the function.
2. And inside `function rate_preprocess_rate_template_emotion(&$variables)` they are using `foreach ($links as $link)`. So make sure that whether you want to do it for all links are just one link.
3. Within `function mytheme_preprocess_rate_template_emotion(&$variables)` put a dpm($variables); and find out which are the variables available to you and what are their values. It might help you.